# Xamarin android save text file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.Android and I want to save a `.txt` file to the SD card. Here is the code that I am using:

```
  private void SavetoSd()
  {
       var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
       var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "iootext.txt");
       if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
       {
           using(System.IO.StreamWriter write = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath,true))
           {
               write.Write(etSipServer.ToString());
           }
       }    
  }
```

However, I receive the following error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   "/mnt/sdcard/iootext.txt" is denied.

I have added the following to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps the dir is not writable (the writable bit not set) or the entire SD is mounted read only.

Comment: If you have added the permissions afterwards, try to uninstall the app on your device, clean the project and rebuild it. Sometimes they get out of sync, because the build process tries to optimize :)

Comment: i uninstaled but it not helped :/

Comment: What version of Android are you running on? If you are running on Marshmallow or later, you will need to ask the user for permission by using the `RequestPermission`. https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Comment: The approach with `var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;` seems to be depricated. I didn't find it so I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61018488/android-os-environment-which-namespace). The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows) shows that its probably easier to use the .Net approach. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Android 6.0+ you will need to perform a runtime check for permissions. This can be done like so:

```
if ((CheckSelfPermission(Permission.ReadExternalStorage) == (int)Permission.Granted) && 
    (CheckSelfPermission(Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == (int)Permission.Granted))
```

More information on this can be found in the android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Answer (score 3):

If file does not exist first create, than get the absolute path and write your data into it.

```
     Java.IO.File sdCard = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;
     Java.IO.File dir = new Java.IO.File (sdCard.AbsolutePath + "/MyFolder");
     dir.Mkdirs ();
     Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File (dir,"iootext.txt");
        if (!file.Exists ()) {
            file.CreateNewFile ();
            file.Mkdir ();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter (file);
            // Writes the content to the file
            writer.Write (jsonData);
            writer.Flush ();
            writer.Close ();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem and after spending couple of hours, I found that if you are running on sdk higher than 23, android version higher than 6, you should implement access request to user. please find more information here on [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) link

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party; but after digging around all day the one thing I found that worked for me is from [this link here](https://www.ictdemy.com/csharp/xamarin/saving-and-loading-data-in-xamarin-using-text-files). The missing piece to my puzzle is to use `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` when reading and writing to the file.

A summary example using the details in the link above, slightly modified for ease of use:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "notes.txt");

// read 
string fileData = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

// write
File.WriteAllText(fileName, fileData);
```