# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/data/user/0/com.haulier_mobile_app.haulier_mobile_app/files/account.json' is denied

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin, and I'm trying create an app to save text files using PCL, but it throws an error saying that I can't access the path. Here's my code:

Portable Class:

```
public void WriteJsonUserVerificationFile(User user)
    {

        var newUser = new User()
        {
            Acct_No = user.Acct_No,

            ROC_No = user.ROC_No,

            Mobile_No = user.Mobile_No,

            Mobile_LoginUserID = user.Mobile_LoginUserID,

            Mobile_LoginPassword = user.Mobile_LoginPassword,

            Expired_Days = user.Expired_Days,

            Expired_Date = user.Expired_Date,

            Is_Verify = user.Is_Verify,

            Verify_Date = user.Verify_Date,

            Verify_Time = user.Verify_Time

        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newUser, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        DependencyService.Get<ISaveAndLoad>().SaveText(json);
    }
```

Droid Class:

```
public void SaveText(string text)
    {
        var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var fileName = Path.Combine(documents, "account.json");
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.haulier_mobile_app.haulier_mobile_app" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.03012017">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<application android:label="HaulierMobileApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon_haulier"></application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And this is the output:

> 01-27 16:24:10.228 E/mono    (20669): Unhandled Exception:
>   01-27 16:24:10.228 E/mono    (20669): System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/data/user/0/com.haulier_mobile_app.haulier_mobile_app/files/account.json' is denied.
>   01-27 16:24:10.228 E/mono-rt (20669): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/data/user/0/com.haulier_mobile_app.haulier_mobile_app/files/account.json' is denied.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you enabled the Permissions, if you are testing on API level 23+ devices in device settings?

Comment: Did you try also enabling `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest? Also, if you're running Android 6.0+ you have to check for [request permissions at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36547258/2399772).

Comment: sorry for late reply, i tested with api 23 device so it return error.. thanks all for the help